# Windows defender sample submission

Tags: windows-7, windows-defender

I recently installed Virtual Clone Drive to mount an Iso on my new Windows 7 64 bit install, and a minute later Windows Defender is asking me if it can submit a sample, which consists of the Virtual Clode Drive executable (VCDMount.exe).

Questions:

1. Is Virtual clone drive suspect?
2. Will submitting it to Microsoft Defender mark it as suspect, even if it isn't?
3. If it's not suspect, and won't be marked as such, why is it being submitted, does Windows Defender maintain white lists as well as black lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Nope, that's what the software is for.
2. No it will just look at it to be sure.
3. I think it's just windows defender being overly cautious.